# How to prevent content from moving down when error message is being shown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this code, when the input is empty and you press submit, an error message pops up, but it pushes the button down, I’m trying to prevent the button from getting pushed down. How can I do this?

This code is also available as a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/zcode99/pen/rNKZWBp).

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const input = document.getElementById("input");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const name = input.value;

  if (name === "") {
    addError("Input field cannot be empty");
  }
});

function addError(message) {
  const small = document.querySelector("small");
  
  small.classList.add("error");
  small.innerText = message;
  small.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.button button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

small {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  width: 15em;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.error small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <form action="" id="form">
    <h1>Please input your user name here</h1>
    <div class="input"><input id="input" type="text" /></div>
    <small></small>
    <div class="button">
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is what the vertical shift looks like before and after the error message appears.
The horizontal lines have been added to compare the positions.

[image: Side-by-side screenshots with horizontal lines added to compare heights. The element has a lower vertical position after the error message appears.]

Answer (score 1):

The `.preventDefault()` does its job, but you should place it into the `if` block. In the following snippet the form will only be submitted if the input field contains some text.

If the problem was the tiny vertical shift introduced by inserting the error message then this can be avoided by keeping it visible at all times with a minimum height and simply changing its `.textContent` accordingly.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const input = document.getElementById("input");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  const name = input.value;

  if (name === "") {
e.preventDefault();
addError("Input field cannot be empty");
  }
});

function addError(message) {
  const small = document.querySelector("small");
  small.classList.add("error");
  small.innerText = message;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.button button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

small {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  width: 15em;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.error small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <form action="somewhereelse.html" id="form">
    <h1>Please input your user name here</h1>
    <div class="input"><input id="input" type="text" /></div>
    <small></small>
    <div class="button">
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this breaks if the error message becomes longer than one line.

Comment: Obviously adjust the `min-height` to the maximum space needed.

Answer (score -1):

**visibility:hidden** hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout. **display:none** removes the element from the document.

you can add following changes in CSS:

```
small {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  width: 15em;
  visibility: hidden;
  height:10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.error small {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

and following Changes in JS

```
function addError(message) {
  const small = document.querySelector("small");
  small.classList.add("error");
  small.innerText = message;
  small.style.visibility= "visible";
}
```

Comment: If the text is not inserted initially, then this won’t solve the problem. The text needs to be _already_ there, at page load. Only then the final space is occupied.

Comment: that is why height 10px is added in CSS

Comment: `height: 10px;` is absolutely not guaranteed to solve the issue! There could be two or more lines of text, the font size could be different, etc. The only way to _guarantee_ that the height will be identical is by having the error message already in place.

Comment: Having the message already there also has its limitations: What if different messages need to be displayed?

Comment: Hey, it worked! Actually, I had to combine your answer with someone else's, where I used ```visibility: hidden``` instead of ```display: none```, and also had to have the error message already inside of the small tag instead of inputting it inside of the Javascript. Thanks!